# How to work with nested hard bracket in d3.js?

Tags: arrays, d3.js

I'm a beginner in d3.js and I need help printing out the data from the arrays of arrays.
Every time I try to print out the data inside the nested hard bracket, the text doesn't show up in browser. I feel frustrated because I'm pretty this is easily fixable but I just can't figure it out. Then I figured I don't have the foundation for the d3.js yet. So far I got this:

```
        //Width and height
        var w = 500;
        var h = 120;
        var barPadding = 1;

        var dataset =[
                [5,23]
                [10,23]
                ];

        var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[0]; })])
                .range([0, w]);

        //Create SVG element
        d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("p")
        .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

Also, if you were able to figure this out, then does your method apply for nested brackets that hold more than 2 digits?

Comment: You will be able to print as is if you fix the dataset declaration: `var dataset =[[5,23],[10,23]];`. It needs a comma between array entries.

Comment: I am not sure what the question is here. Could you explain slightly more clearly what is the output you expect? Maybe this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ctUm/) would help in clarifying your question?

Comment: FernOfTheAndes was able to solve the problem. Thanks you for the comments.

Comment: I will add it as the answer then and you can please accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be able to print as is if you fix the dataset declaration:

```
var dataset =[[5,23],[10,23]];
```

It needs a comma between array entries.